# PowerShell MetaProgramming - Generating Advanced Functions

Tags: powershell, metaprogramming, powershell-2.0

I am looking at dynamically building a bunch of Advanced Functions. I have been using [New-PSScript](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2009/01/02/a-module-to-create-modules-and-advanced-functions.aspx) for this but it doesn't allow for all the flexibility I am looking for.

I was reading the man page for about functions advanced parameters and saw something about Dynamic Parameters at the end of the help article which gives the following sample code

```
function Sample {
      Param ([String]$Name, [String]$Path)

      DynamicParam
      {
        if ($path -match "*HKLM*:")
        {
          $dynParam1 = new-object 
            System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter("dp1",
            [Int32], $attributeCollection)

          $attributes = new-object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
          $attributes.ParameterSetName = 'pset1'
          $attributes.Mandatory = $false

          $attributeCollection = new-object 
            -Type System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection``1[System.Attribute]
          $attributeCollection.Add($attributes)

          $paramDictionary = new-object 
            System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
          $paramDictionary.Add("dp1", $dynParam1)

          return $paramDictionary
        } End if
      }
    }
```

I am wondering if I can use the RuntimeDefinedParameter and the collection of attributes to generate new functions.

Some semi-pseudo code might look like this. The two key functions I (think) I am trying to build are New-Parameter and Add-Parameter.

```
$attributes1 = @{Mandatory=$true;Position=0;ValueFromPipeline=$true}
$param1 = New-Paramater -name foo -attributes $attributes1

$attributes2 = @{Mandatory=$true;Position=1}
$param2 = New-Paramater -name bar -attributes $attributes2

cd function:
$function = new-item -name Get-FooBar -value {"there is a $foo in the $bar"}
Add-Parameter -function $function -paramater $param1,$param2
```

Am I completely barking up the wrong tree? If there are some other ways to do this I am wide open to possibilities.

Comment: The only thing I can see that is missing here is once you've added the parameters, what are you going to do with them?  Unless you are able to modify the function, or your function iterates through a collection of parameters and values...

Comment: I am not completely sure how the flow would work. I was thinking I would create the function Definiton first and then add the parameters to the function. 

In my fake code, I created a function with a value that used the variables I would attach later on as parameters.

Answer (score 3):

In order to create functions on the fly I create the string that defines the function and call Invoke-Expression to compile it and add it to the function provider. This is in my opinion even more powerful than working on the object model.

$f1 = @"
function New-Motor()
{
    "This is my new motor"
}
"@

Invoke-Expression $f1